# Js: Continue if first statement fails

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using node and regex to search multiple text files for a specific piece of information which is present in each file but stored in different way in different files. There are several patterns I've found and I have the following function:

```
function findRegexInText(str, regex) {

let m;
let arr = [];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
        if (match && match.length) {
            arr.push(match.trim());
        }
    });

}
let unique = [...new Set(arr)];

return arr[0];

}
```

In my main function I would like to call a series of searches:

```
       let code;

         code = findRegexInText(substr1, regex1);
         code = findRegexInText(substr2, regex2);
         code = findRegexInText(substr3, regex3);
```

I'd only like to run the second if the first expression comes up empty. and the third if the first 2 fail. What is the best way to do this in JS/Node?

Comment: Why have *a*, *b* and *c*? Consider `let match = findRegexInText(substr1, regex1) || findRegexInText(substr2, regex2) || findRegexInText(substr3, regex3);` so that the value of the first successful call is assigned to *match*. You could also do `[[s1, r1],[s2,r2],...].find([s, r] => findRegxInText(s, r))` to have a variable number of strings and regular expressions to pass.

Comment: I'd put the params to the regex's in an array.  Loop the array and break on the empty condition.

Comment: @danh—…while I was typing… :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function to iterate through an array of substrings and matches and returns the first non-empty result:

```
const searches = [
  [substr1, regex1],
  [substr2, regex2],
  [substr3, regex3],
];
const code = findMatch(searches);
```

```
const findMatch = (searches) => {
  for (const [substr, regex] of searches) {
    const result = findRegexInText(substr, regex);
    if (result) return result;
  }
};
```

Also consider using `matchAll` instead of the ugly `while`:

```
function findRegexInText(str, regex) {
    for (const m of (str.matchAll(regex) || [])) {
        for (const group of m) {
            if (group) {
                return group.trim();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure that would work, but it looks like callback hell. If I had 10 patterns to try if would be harder.

Comment: @user1592380 If you think that's too ugly, it depends on what you're doing with the `a` / `b` / `c` variables, but that isn't shown in the question, so I can't be sure of how to write it. If it were me, I'd put it into a function so you just have to `return` whichever matches first, and feel free to use an array if you think it's clearer.

Comment: Thanks for showing the matchAll approach - can you explain more on 'I'd put it into a function so you just have to return whichever matches first, and feel free to use an array if you think it's clearer.' ?

Comment: @user1592380 It really depends on how you're using the resulting `a`, `b`, and `c` variables. Since that isn't shown in the question, it's hard to say how exactly it'd look.

Comment: I 've edited the question above. I want to assign the first sucessful search to var "code"